# Document Migration in a Single Farm from site collection to site collection

Tags: site-collection, export, document-set

We currently have a single SharePoint 2010 farm with multiple site collections. We have Team sites and then the main portal site.  The plan is to extend our web application into a new Zone for the Team sites.
**The scenario is:**
Teams within their team site will be able to create, approve and then publish their own documents or document sets after they have been approved. Once approved, I would like to provide them the option to publish them to the Portal site.  One document (or document set) library, from one Site collection (team sites) to another document (or document set) library to another Site collection (Portal Site).  We would like to maintain the metadata and content types. 
I would like to write a reusable function that would run when a document was approved to facilitate this migration or export feature.  I would consider writing a service that would allow me to have scheduled jobs.
**MY Question:**
Can this be done? (Logically I say yes, but haven’t found anywhere that anyone is doing this)
What are the pros, cons?
Which is the best solution SPExport or Content Organizer and why?
Does anyone know of any good documented resources to ad in writing my use case requirements. 
I would like to be as flexible as possible to allow for other types of content migration in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out for any others that would like to know.  Sharepoint 2010 has this feature called the Content Organizer.  It work with the files metadate to route it to the approprate file from on Site Collection to another Site Collection.  Both Site Collections have to be set up one to send and one to recieve.  I will share with you a few of sites that I have collected my finding from.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558288.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg650433.aspx#RoutingRecordtoDocumentLibrarySubfolder_Conclusion
http://blog.concurrency.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-content-organizer/

Thanks to these great authors of these websites, that I look great infront of my bosses when I presented this cool feature that has had them pondering for awhile.  :)

the Code Diva!

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this specific scenario, so I'm not sure if having the Web App across different zones would complicate anything, but I would have thought the simplest option would be to use the "[send to](http://angler.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/sharepoint-2010-document-center-send-to-connection-setup-walkthrough/)" feature available on the team site document libraries or site (or even at the farm level) to allow users to publish documents to a document centre with the content organiser enabled on the portal site.

If you needed more control of the approval process and wanted to automate the solution more, there is a [Send Document Set to Repository](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx) workflow task available to use in a custom workflow which could be activated on the team sites...?

Comment: Thank you for your response. And yes I to believe that the "send to" on the Team site would be a simple solution for those who felt comfortable using SharePoint. However my company has a vast array of users starting with those that are not even comfortable using email. So as we introduce this new document application solution with all of it's additional features that you and I understand, I also have to make it as simple and automatic as possible for those who don't. Also depending on the mediadata and the users role, the Sendto could be different each time, and I don't want to have to rely on